# Django: Allow user to re-pick RSVP option

Tags: html

I've been using Django 2.0.6 with python 3.5 to build a wedding website. 
I'm having an issue with allowing the user to change their RSVP selection.

So far, saving user's input works. However, I would like the html to display the 'cocktailchangeform' after the user has already picked something initially. The cocktailchangeform is supposed to overwrite the users previous input. When I look at the 'Attending' under my admin page, there are multiple entries of 'yes' and 'no'. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[Image of Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grlbI.png)

models.py

```
class UserFullName(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
        verbose_name= 'Guest RSVP'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Guests RSVPs'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.get_full_name()


class Guest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserFullName, on_delete='cascade')
    cocktail = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=choice,default='No Response')
```

views.py

```
class CocktailView(FormView):
template_name = 'home/rsvp.html'

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CocktailForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.user = request.user
                post.save()
                form = CocktailForm()
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                form = CocktailForm()
                return redirect('/home')

            args = {'form':form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)


class UpdateCocktail(FormView):
    template_name = 'home/rsvp.html'

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CocktailChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                form = CocktailChangeForm(instance=request.user)
                return redirect('/home')

            args = {'form':form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

forms.py

```
class CocktailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cocktails = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices=choice,
            required=True,
            initial='No Response',
            error_messages={'Required':'Please Select One'},
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ('cocktail',)



class CocktailChangeForm(CocktailForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ('cocktail',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(CocktailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            f = self.fields.get('cocktail', None)
            if f is not None:
                f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')
```

rsvp.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Will you be attending the Thursday evening Cocktail Party?</p><br>
    {% if cocktailform.cocktail is None %}
        <form action="/home/rsvp1/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ cocktailform }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    {% else %}
        <form action="/home/rsvp1/update/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ cocktailchangeform }}
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <h3>You must be logged in to RSVP</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just removed the cocktail update form and the update view. I made one view that determines whether a user has created an object to edit or must create a new one.

```
class CocktailView(FormView):
template_name = 'home/rsvp.html'

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':

            if len(Guest.objects.filter(user=request.user)) == 0:
                form = CocktailForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.user = request.user
                    post.save()
                    return redirect('/home')

            else:
                guest = Guest.objects.get(user=request.user)
                form = CocktailForm(data=request.POST, instance=guest)
                if form.is_valid():
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.save()
                    return redirect('/home')

        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```